# I am storing the mobile numbers in database, but some mobile number are store like e.g. 954E+11,953E+11

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing the mobile numbers in database, but some mobile number are store like e.g. 954E+11,953E+11. I am using datatype to store mobile number as `varchar` with `20`  length.

[image]

Comment: can you change to bigint data type

Comment: Save phone numbers as a varchar.

Comment: Did you write code that stores mobile numbers in your database? If you did, then [edit] your question and add the code since it may contain the reason why your database contains mobile numbers that are not what you expect. By the way, what is the mobile number that you try to store that gives you 954E+11 ?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Is the MySQLi tag relevant or not? YCS has removed it but based on your problem I think it's relevant.

Comment: Your code is quietly converting the strings to integers, but we cannot see your code. You're probably missing an inverted comma somewhere

Answer (score 1):

> The question was altered after/during writing this answer. The previous context was that OP used a number format.

Writing phone numbers as a **number** makes no sense, since you are not doing math operations with it. If you go over a certain range, the number type you chose can store, you will get those *mathematic expressions*.

Instead of, store them as a text datatype like varchar(20) - or the max of numerical characters you expect.

To remove any non number characters you could sanitize the string with a simple regex.

```
$sanitized = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $phoneNumber);
```

Comment: I agree with what you said except the last part. What about +44 country codes? What about extensions?

Comment: In a number the plus is removed also.

Comment: Don't they say in the question *I am use datatype to store mobile number as varchar with 20 length*

Comment: Phone numbers can be longer than 20. What about this number? https://youtu.be/ab8GtuPdrUQ

Comment: Feel free to take more than 20. That was just an example, and as stated *or the max of numerical characters you expect.*

Comment: But surely if they tried to store a longer number it would either throw an error (inserting too long data) or truncate the number and not convert it to *953E+11*

Comment: @NigelRen The question was altered after my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Phone numbers are not mathematical numbers. You can't use numerical data types to store them. You should use `varchar(255)`.

When retrieving it in PHP you must treat it as a string too. Don't perform any mathematical operations on it.

If you use MySQLi, you must bind the parameter in the `bind_param()` as strings (s). E.g.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare ('INSERT INTO phonenumbers(ph_no) VALUES (?)');
$stmt-> bind_param('s', $yourphonenumber);
```

Comment: Same comment as for other answer - they say *I am use datatype to store mobile number as varchar with 20 length.*